# Consequence following from the hypothesis $ : 7$ divides $a^2 + b^2$ with $ a, b \in \mathbb Z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

Not HM, simply self teaching.

Source : Alain Troesch (Louis-le-Grand High School, Paris)  , Exercices $2022-2023$, Polycopié des exercices , page $99$, Ex. $21.10$   http://alain.troesch.free.fr/

> Given ( by hypothesis) that $7 | a^2 + b^2$ with $a, b \in \mathbb Z$.
> Prove that $ 7$ divides both $a$ and $b$.

I only manage to prove the implication $  7|a \implies 7|b^2$ but not $  7|a \implies 7|b$ , even less the desired conjunction.

Proof of the implication :

Since $7 | a^2 + b^2$ ,  it follows that:   $ a^2 + b^2 = 7k , k \in \mathbb Z$.

Now suppose that $7|a$  meaning equivalently that : $ a = 7k'$.

In that case we have :

$(7k')^2 + b^2 = 7k$

$\iff 7^2(k')^2 + b^2 = 7k  $

$\iff b^2 = 7[ k -7(k')^2]$

$ \iff 7 | b^2 $

[image]

Comment: Please [search for answers](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%247%5Cmid%20a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%24%2C%20AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com&p=2) *before* posting questions.

Comment: For the record, some (helpful) comments posted above have been deleted (presumably by a diamond mod).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the properties of primes is that

> Suppose a prime $p\mid ab$ then $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$

This follows from the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Now since $7\mid b\cdot b$ then either $7\mid b$ or $7\mid b$. So $7\mid b$.

Notice that you have only proven that if $7\mid a$ then $7\mid b$. The case still remains where $7\not\mid a,b$. You can now write:

- $a=7m+x$, $1\leq x<7$
- $b=7n+y$, $1\leq y<7$

Then after some algebra $$\begin{align}a^2+b^2&=(7m+x)^2+(7n+y)^2\\&=x^2+y^2+7(7m^2+7n^2+2mx+2my)\end{align}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)